# SQL reserved word syntax error in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am having the following error when trying to execute the following code in phpMyAdmin. I am using WAMP Server with MySQL version 5.5.8 ::

The error is:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NUMERIC(6)   not null, payee  VARCHAR2(20)   not null, amount     DECIMAL(6,2)   no' at line 3
```

the SQL is:

```
CREATE TABLE checks 
    (
        check       NUMERIC(6)  not null,
        payee       VARCHAR2(20)    not null,
        amount      DECIMAL(6,2)    not null,
        remarks     VARCHAR2(20)    not null
    )
```

**EDIT**

I am also trying to execute this but it gives also error:

```
CREATE TABLE deposits
    (
        deposit     NUMBER(8),
        whopaid     VARCHAR(25),
        amount      DECIMAL(6,2),
        remarks     VARCHAR(20)
    )
```

Comment: Replace `VARCHAR2` with `VARCHAR`. It's available in Oracle and not in MySql.

Comment: Thanks you all for your answers and comments. I have edited my post with another SQL that gives error. Can you guys help me out. I think it has no reserved keyword and it should work but it is not

Comment: In your update, the `NUMBER` data type is not available in MySql.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape `check` with backticks since it is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html). And in MySQL there is no `varchar2` data type, just `varchar`.

```
CREATE TABLE checks 
(
    `check`     NUMERIC(6)    not null,
    payee       VARCHAR(20)   not null,
    amount      DECIMAL(6,2)  not null,
    remarks     VARCHAR(20)   not null
)
```

Also replace `NUMBER` with `NUMERIC` in your 2nd create statement.

```
CREATE TABLE deposits
(
    deposit     NUMERIC(8),
    whopaid     VARCHAR(25),
    amount      DECIMAL(6,2),
    remarks     VARCHAR(20)
)
```

[SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f48e1)

See [MySQL String data types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-type-overview.html) and [MySQL numeric data types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html)

Answer (score 0):

`check` is a reserved work, that's why you have this error

you need to put quotes around it

Answer (score 0):

CHECK is a reserved keyword in mysql. If you choose a different name it should work fine.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html